# unable to access template ref variables

Tags: angular, angular6, angular7, parent-child, angular-input

At child.ts, I have a function onButtonClicked which modify revertDisabled from true to false.

Having an issue where the template reference variable at parent.html is still getting value true for revertDisabled variable, even after the user have executed function onButtonClicked() at child.ts which has changed revertDisabled value from true to false.

I have tried solve it by adding @input at parent.ts but still could not access the changed value of revertDisabled .

**parent.html**

```html
<button type="button" [disabled]="interface.revertDisabled"></button>
<interface-settings #interface></interface-settings>
```

---

**child.ts (interface-settings.ts)**

```js
this.revertDisabled = true;

onButtonClicked() {
  this.revertDisabled = false;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes parent won't pickup a value this way. Via template variable you can execute a child's method as described here:
https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-interacts-with-child-via-local-variable

But the guide also says it explicitly:

> The parent component cannot data bind to the child's start and stop
> methods nor to its 'seconds' property.

You can accomplish what you need using @Output and the pattern described here: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-listens-for-child-event

Basically:

```
 //child.ts (interface-settings.ts)

 @Output() revertDisabled = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

 onButtonClicked() {
    this.revertDisabled.emit(false);
 }
```

then:

```
 //  parent.html
 <button #parentButton type="button"></button>
 <interface-settings (revertDisabled)="parentButton.disabled=false"></interface-settings>
```

Comment: Thank you!  Btw Is wondering if you know about this, I have another question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63309569/unable-to-access-template-ref-variables

Comment: seems like you link this very same question? sorry i am confused

Comment: Sorry it is this link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63310432/angular-how-do-i-access-the-reference-variable-which-is-in-a-ng-template

Comment: answered that question for you. If this one here helped - please accept the answer and same for the other answer. Cheers!

Comment: I will try the suggestion for the other question. I've accepted the answer for this question. Thanks much!